# Loading XML configuration files in OSGi

Tags: xml, configuration, osgi

I would like to load configuration data for a bundle in the OSGi environment (FUSE ESB 4.3.1). Spring DM provides abstraction of the Configuration Admin and allows to read the properties files in etc folder.

What I want to achieve is to load an XML file, since I need a configuration of greater complexity than simple properties file. An example could be:

```
<measurements>
  <measurementsList name="First">
    <measurement>First-1</measurement>
    <measurement>First-2</measurement>
  </measurementsList>
  <measurementsList name="Second">
    <measurement>Second-1</measurement>
    <measurement>Second-2</measurement>
    <measurement>Second-3</measurement>
    <measurement>Second-4</measurement>
  </measurementsList>
   ...
</measurements>
```

and then to parse it to get a Map> where the key is the name of measurementsList and value is the list of the measurement names.

How can I do it in OSGi? Where do I need to place my file for it to be accessible from a certain bundle?

Best wishes,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Save the configuration in a separate XML file. Pass the file name or the URL as a string value in a property managed by the Configuration Admin. In the configurable object, open the file and read/process the XML contents there.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the XML file in etc folder under servicemix, and pass the relative path in the spring DM config admin.

```
<bean ...>
    <osgix:managed-properties persistent-id="com.sample.your.config.location.path" />
    <property name="config-path" value="etc/config.xml"/> 
</bean>
```

relative path works relative off servicemix directory